# Checkout BitBucket Android Studio project in Android Studio

Tags: android, git

I am trying to pull a new project into Android Studio, the project has been pushed by a fellow person using Android Studio, Android Studio has not made this easy at all. I have done the following.

Remote Repository:
[image]

Start of checkout(I click on clone):
[image]

After it clones, the files:

[image]
[image]

This is where I am unsure what I am supposed to do, I try importing:

[image]

Am I supposed to import `fela` or `app`?

If I choose `app` it states this:

[image]

The file structure is not the same as my other projects, as shown here:

[image]

This also complains:

[image]

If I choose `fela` it states:

[image]

To put salt in the wound, I press cancel, and it continues anyway.

How should I import this project?

Answer (score 1):

When you import the project after checkout select the build.gradle instead of root of directory of your check out project.

Comment: Results in the same effect as choosing the app directory!

Comment: If it is not private project can you share your bitbucket link

Comment: You should be able to see it now!

Answer (score 0):

while importing project don't select app or fela just select build.gradle which is inside app folder. and it will ask for gradle package. please allow it to be downloaded once after that you can successfully use your project.

Ask if anything needed?
Hope it helps !!

Comment: Results in the same effect as choosing the app directory!

Answer (score 0):

From the structure there it seems like you are missing a build.gradle file in the projects root folder "fela". At least on all projects I've done there has been a build.gradle in the root and one in the app directory. You might want to check with the person that pushed it if they included the roots build.gradle file. I hope this helps.